Approximating the Hessian in Laplace's approximation
I need to understand the motivation behind certain approximations of the Hessian often used in Laplace's approximation.
Let's assume we're trying to do regression with a neural network, and we want approximate the posterior on the network parameters $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ as Gaussian.
Given a set of $n$ training pairs $\{ (\mathbf{x}_{i}, \mathbf{y}_{i} ) \}_{i=1}^{n}$ and assuming IID observations, the posterior distribution on the parameters is given by
\begin{align}
p( \boldsymbol{\theta} \, | \, \mathbf{y}_{1:n}, \mathbf{x}_{1:n}) \propto p(\boldsymbol{\theta}) \prod_{i=1}^{n} p(\mathbf{y}_{i} \, | \, \mathbf{x}_{i}, \boldsymbol{\theta}) 
\end{align}
where $p(\boldsymbol{\theta}) = \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\theta} \, ; \, \boldsymbol{\mu}, \boldsymbol{\Sigma})$ is a Gaussian with mean $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ and covariance $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$.
To approximate the posterior as Gaussian, we first determine the mode of the posterior $\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}$, and then we approximate the posterior precision using the Hessian of the negative log likelihood of the posterior:
\begin{align*}
\hat{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}}^{-1} &= \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1} + n \mathbf{H},\\
\mathbf{H} &= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} - \nabla_{\boldsymbol{\theta}}^{2} \log p(\mathbf{y}_{i} \, | \, \mathbf{x}_{i}, \boldsymbol{\theta}) \big|_{\boldsymbol{\theta} = \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}}
\end{align*}
The matrix $\mathbf{H}$ is sometimes approximated using the Fisher information matrix,
\begin{align}
\mathbf{F} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathbb{E}_{ \mathbf{y} \sim p(\mathbf{y} \, | \, \mathbf{x}_{i},  \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}})  } \left[ \left( \nabla_{\boldsymbol{\theta}} \log p(\mathbf{y} \, | \, \mathbf{x}_{i}, \boldsymbol{\theta}) \big|_{\boldsymbol{\theta} = \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}} \right) \left(  \nabla_{\boldsymbol{\theta}} \log p(\mathbf{y} \, | \, \mathbf{x}_{i}, \boldsymbol{\theta}) \big|_{\boldsymbol{\theta} = \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}}\right)^{\top} \right],
\end{align}
or the "empirical Fisher" information matrix,
\begin{align*}
\hat{\mathbf{F}} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( \nabla_{\boldsymbol{\theta}} \log p(\mathbf{y}_{i} \, | \, \mathbf{x}_{i}, \boldsymbol{\theta}) \big|_{\boldsymbol{\theta} = \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}} \right) \left(  \nabla_{\boldsymbol{\theta}} \log p(\mathbf{y}_{i} \, | \, \mathbf{x}_{i}, \boldsymbol{\theta}) \big|_{\boldsymbol{\theta} = \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}}\right)^{\top}.
\end{align*}
How are these approximations related to one another, and how do I derive them?
Based on my limited understanding, we do the following:
We assume there is some distribution $p(\mathbf{x})$ over the inputs so that $p(\mathbf{y}, \mathbf{x} \, | \, \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}) = p(\mathbf{y} \, | \, \mathbf{x}, \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}) \, p(\mathbf{x})$, and we assume the following holds
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}_{(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) \sim p(\mathbf{y}, \mathbf{x} \, | \, \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}})} \left[ -\nabla_{\boldsymbol{\theta}}^{2} \log p(\mathbf{y} \, | \, \mathbf{x}, \boldsymbol{\theta}) \big|_{\boldsymbol{\theta} = \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}} \right] 
= \mathbb{E}_{(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) \sim p(\mathbf{y}, \mathbf{x} \, | \, \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}})} \left[ \left( \nabla_{\boldsymbol{\theta}} \log p(\mathbf{y} \, | \, \mathbf{x}, \boldsymbol{\theta}) \big|_{\boldsymbol{\theta} = \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}} \right) \left(  \nabla_{\boldsymbol{\theta}} \log p(\mathbf{y} \, | \, \mathbf{x}, \boldsymbol{\theta}) \big|_{\boldsymbol{\theta} = \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}}\right)^{\top} \right].
\end{align}
The distribution on $\mathbf{x}$ is typically unknown, we use an empirical distribution in its place so that $p(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \delta(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}_{i})$, where $\delta(\mathbf{x})$ is the Dirac delta.
If we substitute this empirical distribution into the expectation on the right-hand side of the above equation, we obtain the Fisher information matrix $\mathbf{F}$.
Based on this, if we allow $p(\mathbf{y} \, | \, \mathbf{x}_{i}, \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}})$ in the definition of $\mathbf{F}$ to be an empirical distribution, then we obtain $\hat{\mathbf{F}}$.
If we apply both empirical distributions to the left-hand expectation above, then we obtain $\mathbf{H}$.
This feels very flimsy to me, especially using an empirical distribution for $p(\mathbf{y} \, | \, \mathbf{x}_{i}, \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}})$ -- the only distribution I can think of is $p(\mathbf{y} \, | \, \mathbf{x}_{i}, \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}) = \delta(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{y}_{i})$.

You might want to review your notation !

The answers here might help.
